# tkinter how to store a number from an entry box so every entry is added to the next

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to write a program where you enter a number in to an entry box click a button and it prints the number you entered and it prints the number you entered multiplied by 0.008.

Then stores the numbers so the next time you enter a number it adds it to the previous number and prints it and so on so forth. I have written the first bit of code and it works well. But no matter how much research I do I cannot find out how to do the second bit. This is my code so far.

```
from tkinter import *

def calculatemoney():
    done = float(Lines1.get())
    salary3 = done * 0.08
    salary4 = done * 1


    labelresult = Label(root, text='%.0f' % salary4).grid(row=3, column=2)
    labelresult = Label(root, text=' £ %.2f' % salary3).grid(row=4, column=2)

root = Tk()


root.title('Dict8 Calc')
root.geometry('250x200+800+100')
Lines1 = StringVar()
var1 = Label(root, text='Enter Lines').grid(row=0, column=1)
var2 = Label(root, text='Lines Today').grid(row=3, column=1)
var3 = Label(root, text='Money Today').grid(row=4, column=1)
var4 = Label(root, text='Lines Total').grid(row=6, column=1)
var5 = Label(root, text='Money Total').grid(row=7, column=1)
myLines = Entry(root, textvariable=Lines1).grid(row=0, column=2)

button1 = Button(root, text='  Calculate  ', command=calculatemoney).grid(row=8, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from using a regular variable ?

```
from tkinter import *

def calculatemoney():
    global oldValue                             # Making it global so you can set it's value
    done = float(Lines1.get())
    salary3 = done * 0.08
    salary4 = done
    salary5 = (done + oldValue) * 0.8           # Adding the old value to the new one
    salary6 = done + oldValue


    Label(root, text='%.0f' % salary4).grid(row=3, column=2)        # I don't recommend this method of putting a label over another every time the user activates this function
    Label(root, text=' f %.2f' % salary3).grid(row=4, column=2)
    Label(root, text='%.0f' % salary6).grid(row=6, column=2)
    Label(root, text=' f %.2f' % salary5).grid(row=7, column=2)

    oldValue += done            # Adding the current value to the old value

root = Tk()

oldValue = 0.0          # Define variable that will represent an old value 

root.title('Dict8 Calc')
root.geometry('250x200+800+100')
Lines1 = StringVar()
var1 = Label(root, text='Enter Lines').grid(row=0, column=1)        # .grid() method returns 'None' so you dont have any use for 'var1'.
var2 = Label(root, text='Lines Today').grid(row=3, column=1)
var3 = Label(root, text='Money Today').grid(row=4, column=1)
var4 = Label(root, text='Lines Total').grid(row=6, column=1)        # Shouldn't it be 'row=5' ? 
var5 = Label(root, text='Money Total').grid(row=7, column=1)
myLines = Entry(root, textvariable=Lines1).grid(row=0, column=2)

button1 = Button(root, text='  Calculate  ', command=calculatemoney).grid(row=8, column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Nice one Stevo Mitric as I say I'm a very new beginner at python and tkinter and I have not come across global before all the you tube tutorials I have watched have not mentioned the yet I shall research global now thanks